# Is there a way to clear filters on a PBI report without using bookmark

Tags: powerbi

Is there a way to let users clear filter on a PBI report page without having to set up a bookmark or other complex coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

End users can use the highlighted button to clear filters

[image: ClearFilter]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is what you meant, but the yellow arrow in the top right lets the user reset all their changes and restores the PowerBI to the default filtering (what it was set to when you uploaded it)

[yellow arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YnzR.png)